# Mostrar la lista de tags de la coleccion

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb

Estoy haciendo una API que muestra una colección de anuncios de productos con MongoDB y Node.js

Necesito mostrar la lista de tags de todos los productos en una cadena JSON.

Seria esto lo que quiero mostrar:  'mobile', 'work', 'motor, 'lifestyle'

Este es el código inicializador del API:

```
const readline = require('readline');


const Product = require('./models/Product');

async function main() {

  const advance = await question('Are you sure to continue with the deletion of the database? (yes or no) ')
  if (!advance) {
    process.exit();
  }

  const connection = require('./lib/connectMongoose')

  await initProducts();


  connection.close();
}

async function initProducts() {
  const deleted = await Product.deleteMany();
  console.log(`Remove ${deleted.deletedCount} products.`);

  const inserted = await Product.insertMany([
    {name: 'table', sale: true, price: 150, photo: 'table.png', tags: ['work']},
    {name: 'iphone 13 pro', sale: false, price: 950, photo: 'iphone13pro.png', tags: ['mobile']},
    {name: 'car mini cooper', sale: true, price: 1000, photo: 'carminicooper.png', tags: ['motor']},
    {name: 'chair', sale: false, price: 300, photo: 'chair.png', tags: ['lifestyle']}
  ]);

  console.log(`Create ${inserted.length} products.`)
  
}


main().catch(err => console.log('Hubo un error', err))

async function question(text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const interface = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });
    interface.question(text, answer => {
      interface.close();
      if (answer.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
        resolve(true);
        return;
      }
      resolve(false);
    })
  })
}
```

No puedo hacerlo a traves de un filtro porque me mostraria el nombre del campo antes del valor de cada tag.

Busco un modo de consulta de Mongo DB con Node.js que me permita mostrar la lista de tags.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar `distinct` de MongoDB que devuelve un array con los valores distintos de un campo específico y luego `JSON.stringify`.

```
const tags = await Product.distinct('tags');
console.log(tags); // ['work', 'mobile', 'motor', 'lifestyle']

const tagsJSON = JSON.stringify(tags);
console.log(tagsJSON); // ['work', 'mobile', 'motor', 'lifestyle']
```

Para mostrarlo en el cliente puedes enviarlo como respuesta a la solicitud http por medio de una ruta, quedaría algo así:

```
app.get('/api/products/tags', async (req, res) => {
  const tags = await Product.distinct('tags');
  res.json(tags);
});
```

Comment: Pero como haria para mostrarlo cuando llamo a la ruta del API? necesito mostrarlo alli, no en la consola

Comment: Hola, acabo de editar mi respuesta con lo que comentas

Comment: @EmilyHeredia me había olvidado mencionarte jaja

Comment: Hola Edward si pude resolverlo como dijiste, lo estaba incluyendo en una parte del codigo donde no funcionaba